# How to change BackColor of WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#

I have made a broswer in C# and I want to change the backcolor of WebBrowser to transparent that the text only appear. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would be better if you show us your work. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 2):

Back/Foreground colors of a WebBrowser control are controlled by the content of the document you're displaying.

But if you want to change the color before loading any content, use this:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body style='background-color:Blue'></body></html>";
```